# How to pass a particular row to ajax function in View in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter and i want to pass row returned from controller via model to ajax function in a view.
The following code shows how i am getting data from model to controller but cannot pass data to ajax function
in a view.I am getting null value in success section of ajax.

> Model:

```
public function get_last_course_rec($last_id)
{
   $this->db->where('id',$last_id);
   $update=$this->db->get('course');
   $get_row=$update->row();
}
```

> Controller:

```
public function create_course_goal(){


    $id=$this->input->post('c_id');  

    $result_updated_record = $this->course_model->get_last_course_rec($id);

    if($result_updated_record!='false')
    { 
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result_updated_record));

    }
    else
    {   
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result_updated_record));
    }

}
```

> View:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>create/create_goal",
    cache: false,               
    data: dataString,
        dataType:'JSON',
    success: function(data){
        alert("data"+data);
        },
    error: function(){                      
    alert('Error while request..');
    }
   });
```

Comment: Check your browser console for error also post code of function `create_goal`  as you use url `<?php echo base_url();?>create/create_goal` in ajax call

Comment: No there is no error in the console

Comment: you mistake in ajax url: use  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>controllername/create_course_goal",

Comment: Sorry that was error in typing

Comment: also `dataString` is undefined in your code!!

Comment: @user3653474 please print your result and check if it is ther or not.use print_r($result_updated_record);

Comment: use this code.$results['message'] = $result_updated_record;    
$json = json_encode($results); and fetch by "data.message".

Comment: -Thanks it solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Echo Your Result,

```
public function create_goal(){


    $id=$this->input->post('c_id');  

    $result_updated_record = $this->course_model->get_last_course_rec($id);

    if($result_updated_record!='false')
    { 
        echo json_encode($result_updated_record);
    }
    else
    {   
        echo json_encode($result_updated_record);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please check url of ajax call it call `<?php echo base_url();?>create/create_goal` not `create_course_goal()`

Comment: It is printing data null

Answer (score 1):

model should be like this

```
public function get_last_course_rec($last_id)
{
   return $this->db->select('course')->from('table_name')->where('id',$last_id)->get()->row();

}
```

controller

```
$result_updated_record = $this->course_model->get_last_course_rec($id);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if($result_updated_record)
    { 
       echo json_encode($result_updated_record);

    }
    else
    {   
        echo json_encode("no result");
    }
```